# Check if the network connectivity type is 2G, 3G, 4G or WiFi in Appcelerator Mobile app?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am working on an app in Appcelerator Titanium 5.2 SDK, which requires a stable internet connection during the `sync` process.

I want to limit the app to do work, only when its online and the network connection type is either `3G`, `4G` or `WiFi`. I don't want the app to sync via a slow connection such as `2G`, `EDGE`, `GPRS` etc...

How can I achieve this in appcelerator titanium mobile app?

I can check through out my app if it's online or not using this method:

```
Alloy.Globals.online = Ti.Network.online;
Ti.Network.addEventListener( 'change', function( e ) {
    Alloy.Globals.online = e.online;
});
```

This only tells me the connection state, however the connection type info I am after is not available. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I know you can use Ti.Network.networkTypeName or Ti.Network.networkType as explained here: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network-property-networkTypeName
But I'm not sure if this is enough for you. The second thing I can recommend you is this module: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Pinger
It's just a tool to check if the user has internet or not ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `Network type as a String. Returns one of NONE, WIFI, LAN, MOBILE, or UNKNOWN` - this doesn't tell you if its 2g, 3g, 4g etc... and i dont need a module to check when i am online or not. The code I posed above is sufficient.

Comment: it returns you if it is mobile or wifi...at least is something. And Ti.Network.online sucks, because if you are connected but have some problems in the network, it will returns you true...just trying to help you mate

Answer (score 1):

We have created a native iOS module for this. Unfortunately, this module is not yet available as open source. If you are familiar with modules, this should help you to get started (filename: MobileNetworkType.m):

```
#import "MobileNetworkType.h"
@import CoreTelephony;

@interface MobileNetworkType ()

@end

@implementation MobileNetworkType

- (NSString *)getMobileDataConnectionType {
  CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
  NSString *radioAccessTechnology =       telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology;

if ([radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS]) {
    return @"GPRS";
} else if ([radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge]) {
    return @"Edge";
} else if ([radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA]
           || [radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA]
           || [radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA]
           || [radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x]
           || [radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0]
           || [radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA]
           || [radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB]
           || [radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD]) {
    return @"3G";
} else if ([radioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
    return @"LTE";
}
return @"Unknown";
}

@end
```

and(filename: MobileNetworkType.h):

```
@interface MobileNetworkType : NSObject 
-(NSString *) getMobileDataConnectionType;
@end
```